# PL/SQL - object which has method with parameter and returns sum of one type row

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

I am new in PL/SQL and having problem with PL/SQL

I want to write object method which has parameter shop name (in the table) and returns total amount of goods in shop.

```
Let`s say name of shop could be "Center".

CREATE TYPE SHOPS_TYP AS OBJECT (
    S_NUM NUMBER,
    S_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    TEL VARCHAR2(20)
);
/

CREATE TYPE GOODS_T AS OBJECT(
   G_NUM NUMBER,
   G_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
   G_QUANTITY NUMBER,
   G_PRICE NUMBER,
   NUM_SHOP REF SHOPS_TYP,
   ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION total(x GOODS_T) RETURN INTEGER
);
/


CREATE TABLE GOODS OF GOODS_TYP;

CREATE TYPE BODY GOODS_TYP AS 

ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION total(x GOODS_TYP) RETURN INTEGER IS

BEGIN

  RETURN (SELECT SUM(G.G_NUM) FROM GOODS G WHERE G.NUM_SHOP.S_NAME = x);
END;
END;

SELECT Value(A) from GOODS A where A.total('centers');
```

When I run the code above I am getting error in "RETURN" part of method. How can I implement this query ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html

Answer (score 1):

`Return` has to return an expression. The [documentation defines expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/expression.html#GUID-D4700B45-F2C8-443E-AEE7-2BD20FFD45B8) as:

> "an arbitrarily complex combination of operands (variables, constants, literals, operators, function invocations, and placeholders) and operators"

This does not include a result set, so change your method to look like this:

```
ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION total(x GOODS_TYP) RETURN INTEGER IS

    return_value number;

BEGIN

   SELECT SUM(G.G_NUM)
   into return_value
   FROM GOODS G WHERE G.NUM_SHOP.S_NAME = x;

   RETURN return_value;
END;
```

---

By the way, you should make life easier for yourself and your colleagues by using one naming convention for your objects.